# how to get the distance from RSSI in veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins, rssi

I found how to get the RSSI value in veins in this link: [how to record rssi in veins (omnet++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562956/how-to-record-rssi-in-veins-omnet/54594801#54594801)

I want to know now how to get the distance between two nodes based on the RSSI value?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to another post (links below), you could generate a simple look-up table: have one vehicle drive past another one, record distance and RSSIs, and you have a table that can map RSSI to distance. For details check

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54270962/7215379.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39468731/7215379.